# jQuery-textcomplete Integration with CKEditor / TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, ckeditor, tinymce

I tried to integrate [jquery-textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete) with ckeditor and with tinyMCE.

I got this error.

```
TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.issue_notes is undefined
```

Can you give me a little help to integrate jQuery-textcomplete with CKEditor / TinyMCE. You can look code sample here, https://jsfiddle.net/btjapqkp/

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.5.10/adapters/jquery.js">
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  tinymce.init({ selector:'#three' });
  $('#two').ckeditor();
  $('.editable').textcomplete([{
    match: /(^|\b)(\w{2,})$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
      var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'github', 'microsoft', 'yahoo'];
      callback($.map(words, function (word) {
        return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
      }));
    },
    replace: function (word) {
      return word + ' ';
    }
  }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a bug in the jquery-textcomplete. Look at bellow URL to fix that issue. This solution will be merged to the jquery-texcomplete in near future. Then you don't need to follow bellow solution.

https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete/issues/285